# Compile FFmpeg as iOS 8 Framework

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, xcode6

I successfully compiled FFmpeg with iOS 8.2 SDK thanks to https://github.com/kewlbear/FFmpeg-iOS-build-script and last version of gas-preprocessor (https://github.com/libav/gas-preprocessor).

However, I would like to package FFmpeg libraries as a iOS 8 dynamic framework due to legal constraints. I found resources to create iOS 8 dynamic framework however I cannot find any solution for FFmpeg.

Can anyone help me to package these librairies ?
Thanks
David

Comment: Hey zebeurton can you help with that framework, have you got the last version of FFMpeg compiled compatible with all the architectures?

Comment: Guys, keep in mind that ffmpeg performance on video will be a LOT worse than using the built in H.264 encoder/decoder hardware in iOS devices. Also, there are LGPL license issues that you will need to get legal advice on: http://multinc.com/2009/08/24/compatibility-between-the-iphone-app-store-and-the-lgpl/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, FFmpeg-iOS repo in Github can build static libraries from FFmpeg source code. But I search throughout the network, no one show me how to compile with dynamic libraries.

But I wonder if we can create a new cocoa touch framework project, and drag all header files and libraries into this project, and do some header declaration into the base .h file, and drag the framework project into an existing iOS project as a sub project, add it as an embedded framework, and compile the whole project.

The reason why I use sub project, instead of giving out a final .framework file, is that static symbols can only be linked only if them are been using somewhere.

I will demonstrate this later. If anyone has better ideas, it will be grateful.

Edit:
After several days's researching, I found it is not easy to build dynamic framework easily, but I find a workaround to achieve the target:

1. Build a static libraries of FFmpeg
2. Create a new iOS dynamic framework project
3. Create a class that encapsulate the basic usage of the FFmpeg, such as encoding/decoding video
4. Copy static libraries into this dynamic framework project
5. Make sure your project build without error
6. Add this project as a subproject to your existing project
7. Add dependency in embedded binaries and Linked Frameworks and Libraries
8. Build and run main project
9. Open source this project as LGPL2.1+, the same as FFmpeg itself.

Through it is not perfect, but at least it works, and it complies with FFmpeg's LGPL license.